Quiko gate opener reports "motor in thermal protection"
I have a Quiko QK-CE220BATRL4 circuit board controlling two Quiko motors on each gate.
It has been working fine for the last 3 years.
Now when I click the remote button the circuit board still registers the press but the gate does not open.
The display on the circuit board is "9a" which the instruction booklet describes as:

9a: Motor A is in thermal protection state

The only reference to this in the booklet is a "Motor Thermal Test" which simply says the  working cycle cannot be started if the motor is in thermal protection, which is, I assume, why my gate will not open or close.
So the question is what is thermal protection state, why has it suddenly occured, and what should I do to fix it?
I have obviously tried turning off and on!

Some electric motors have a cut-out circuit built into them for protecting the motor from high temperatures. Some have separate thermal monitoring/protection arrays that interact with the motor control circuit. They might reset automatically when cool or might have a reset button on the motor case (or elsewhere in the control scheme). Other than "turning off and on", you may need to physically reset via a button on the motor, or there may be a "reset" function within the control interface. No telling why it occurred... over-use, overload, fault, etc...

Can you move(open/close) the gates by hand?  If so see if there is any jamming/tightness that might have caused the motor/s to over heat.

There's two overall possibilities here: bad connection or failed component.
As it says in the manual, the thermal test may fail if the motor is badly connected. The fix to this is simple: redo the motor connections so they are clean and tight.
If that simple fix doesn't work, you will need to investigate a few other items. One is that you have a failed motor which is actually in thermal protection. The other is that some part of the circuit which tests for thermal failure has failed. Without board-level diagnosis, you're left to do parts substitution to determine which fault has actually occurred.
The first substitution you can do is swapping the connections between Motor A and Motor B. If the thermal failure moves with the connection swap, you have a bad motor. If it doesn't move with the connection swap, you have a bad control board.
Note that to do this you might need to physically disconnect the motors from the gate, depending on the mechanical interlock of how the gate opens, since the controller always operates motor A followed by Motor B.

Thanks, I swapped the connections and the error message stayed with "9a", so I assume the issue is with the board and not the motor. I then also checked all three fuses on the board - none were faulty. I checked all the wiring - its pretty tight and was well installed and locked away, no reason for anything to have changed.
The last thing I will do (although not optimistic) is get a key and manually move the gates to the closed position rather than the open positions and see if it makes any difference, perhaps they are "locked" in place by some non-lubricated mechanism.

It's worth a try, but I'm not particularly optimistic about it since the problem stayed even when you swapped motors. Definitely validate it though!
